# Can install python36 on RHEL7 with IBM PPC architecture?

Tags: python-3.6, rhel7, powerpc

I have searched for python36u package for RHEL7 with ppc architecture and I fail to find it.

I try below command on shell

`sudo yum install python36u.ppc64le`

and it downloads python36u package for `x86_64` architecture.

Even `python36u.ppc64le` package is not found on Centos mirror.

Do I need to compile whole python36 source on powerpc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `python36u` packages are provided by the 'ius' repository, not the core RHEL7 repos.

Additionally, it seems like the ius pacakges are not built for ppc64el.

However, there do seem to be `python36` (ie, not `python36u`) packages floating around for ppc64el though, in the epel collection:

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python36